# Metadata API Deployment Failure

Tags: visualforce, deployment, deployment-api

I am trying to deploy Weblink from Task Object to the Activity object , but it says "no WebLink found ObjectName.FieldName.

Here is the Activity.object XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <searchLayouts>
      <listViewButtons>update_activity</listViewButtons>
   </searchLayouts>
</CustomObject>
```

Here is the package.xml definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>Activity</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
  </types>
  <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: A [WebLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_weblink.htm) has it's own dedicated Metadata type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
      <types>
        <members>Activity.update_activity</members>
        <name>Weblink</name>
      </types>
      <version>36.0</version>
    </Package>
```

Comment: It didn't work !

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: The error is - Error: In field: listViewButtons - no WebLink named Activity.activities__Mass_Update found

Comment: please check if activities__Mass_Update is the correct api name of the button. I tried the same xml with a button on task object, in my developer org and it worked fine.  your button seems to have a different namespace than default one. i would check on that as well.